# My XML document is not finding the schema in a different source folder in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

I have an Eclipse project with 2 source folders: src and test. My xml schema is located in the src folder, while my sample xml document is located in the test folder. Within their source folders, they are located in the same package (IOW, the schema is src/top-level-package/schema.xds and the xml is test/top-level-package/sample-xml.xml).

The top of my xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
```

When the xml document was in the same package as the schema, this worked. Now, however, I am getting this warning: "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document."

I tried going up the tree and then walking down into the correct folder like this: `../../src/top-level-package/schema.xsd`, but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It must be that your validator doesn't handle correctly the relative URIs - yours are perfectly fine and work with other processors. To analyse, from a configuration that works (in the same folder for example) try with ./schema.xsd, then ../top-level-package/schema.xsd, etc. See when it fails, or maybe you find something that works in your case.

Comment: I assume `src` and `test` are both included as source paths in your build path configuration and source path property EXCLUDED is (None)? If yes try Workspace Preferences > XML > XML Catalog to temporarily add your schema.